# Can I servc static files with squid?

Tags: squid, file-sharing

I have a set of files which doesn't change very often. I am wondering if it is possible to avoid an additional installation of nginx or similar, if these files would be added to squid as "static"  content. All users have to use the squid proxy anyway.  So instead of going to his cache, squid would just serve these files from a local dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

But setting up a simple webserver like Lighttpd, nginx or g-wan is trivial and will not require a lot of server resource. And with the URL rewriter you can patch the HTTP requests easily.